# PySimpleGUI tables - unable to create list of lists

Tags: python, list, pysimplegui

I'm unable to use PySimpleGUI.Table because of my inability to create list of lists, please see my code:

```
def is_compiled(file):
    full_path = main_path + 'models_data/'+ file[:-3]
    return isdir(full_path)   #Returns bool True of False


models_src = [f for f in listdir(model_src_path) if isfile(join(model_src_path, f))] 
is_compiled_list = [str(is_compiled(f)) for f in models_src] 
table_list = [models_src,is_compiled_list]
print(table_list)
```

printing my lists shows:

> [['CNN_v1.py', 'test.py'], ['False', 'True']]

and type is <class 'list'>

But when I try to put this list into sg.Table:

```
table_headings = ['name','iscompiled?']
layout = [[sg.Table(table_list,headings=table_headings]]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, margins=(500, 300))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
```

I'm getting this error message:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not Text

I know this is probably a very simple solution but I was trying to find it for hours and I couldn't. Thanks for help!

EDIT:Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception maybe caused by the code you not show here.

For example, in following code, `[sg.Table(table_list, headings=table_headings)]` come with `[sg.Text('Hellow World')]` at next line.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

table_list = [['CNN_v1.py', 'test.py'], ['False', 'True']]
table_headings = ['name','iscompiled?']
layout = [
    [sg.Table(table_list, headings=table_headings)]
    [sg.Text('Hellow World')]
]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

It is something like following code, `sg.Text('Hellow World')` will be thought as the index of `list1`, that's why you got exception `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Text`

```py
list1 = [sg.Table(table_list, headings=table_headings)]
layout = [
    list1[sg.Text('Hellow World')]
]
```

It should be with a comma between any two items in a list, like

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

table_list = [['CNN_v1.py', 'test.py'], ['False', 'True']]
table_headings = ['name','iscompiled?']
layout = [
    [sg.Table(table_list, headings=table_headings)],    # A comma missed between any two items
    [sg.Text('Hellow World')]
]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are a genius! List was all right all the time, all I was missing was a comma between Table entry and next line in layout.

Comment: I'll add this specific error message to the documentation.  It's an error I make frequently as well.... pesky commas.  It's not an error I can "catch" in the PySimpleGUI code itself because it's localized to your program.  The best I think I can do is document the exact error message in case someone does a search.