# PYSIMPLEGUI TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm trying to create a GUI using PYSIMPLEGUI. I'm having a problem when I try to open my second window. The variable `output2`should be showing the user's answer. Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Black')
myImg = sg.Image(filename='logo_meca_pret.png',size=(200,200))
output = sg.Text(font=("Arial",20))
output3 = sg.Text(font=("Arial",20))
output4 = sg.Input(key="w_a")

def window2():
    
    output2 = sg.Text(font=("Arial",20))
    
    layout2 = [
          [sg.Text('PROGRAMA DE TREINAMENTOS',font=("Arial",60),justification="center")],
          [sg.Text("Nao ha novos tutoriais disponiveis.",font=("Arial",20))],
          [sg.Text("Deseja assistir algum tutorial novamente?",font=("Arial",20)),sg.InputText(size=(1),key="w_a")],  
          [output2]        
          [sg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)]
]
    window = sg.Window("TUTORIAIS JA VISTOS", layout2,element_justification="center", modal=True,finalize=True)
    window.Maximize()

    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        w_a = values["w_a"]        
        output2.update(w_a)
        #print(output2)
    window.close()

layout = [
         [myImg,sg.Text('PROGRAMA DE TREINAMENTOS',font=("Arial",60),justification="center")],
         [sg.Text("Passe o cracha no leitor: ",font=("Arial",20)),sg.InputText(size=(60),key="ID")],
         [output],
         [sg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)]
]

window = sg.Window('PROGRAMA DE TREINAMENTOS MERCEDES BENZ', layout,element_justification="center").Finalize()
window.Maximize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
```

What can

```
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    #print('You entered ', values[0])
    if event == 'Submit':    
        ID = values["ID"]   
        if is_registered(ID) == True:            
            name,section = current_user_data(users_df,ID)
            output.update(f"Ola, {name}, bem vindo ao programa de treinamento Mercedes Benz Brasil!\n")
            videos = videos_to_watch(section,ID)
            if is_list_empty(videos,section,ID) == True:                
                window2()
                

window.close()
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\TESTE\teste.py", line 72, in <module>
    window2()
  File "d:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\TESTE\teste.py", line 34, in window2 
    [output2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button
```

Comment: A comma missed after `[output2]` in your layout2, Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70970950/11936135

Comment: now i'm embarrassed hahhaha, thanks

Comment: I would like to be able to catch these and report them to users, but I don't see how I can as it's all in the ser's code.